# Kendo Grid Change Displayed Value

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Given an initialized and displayed Kendo Grid.  I want to change the value on a column when either the detailExpand or detailCollapse event occurs.  How do I change a displayed value?  This is an MVVM initialized grid, but it appears that changes to the data source do not update the displayed values in the grid.  So much for data binding.

```
OnDetailCollapse: function(e) {
    var self = ScenarioManager.MasterGridViewModel;

    var data = e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow);

    var product = self.FindProductById(self.get('Products').data(), data.Id);

    product.set('MrcDisplay', product.MrcSubTotal); // This does nothing
    product.set('NrcDisplay', product.NrcSubTotal); // This does nothing
},
```

Comment: You should try changing it by selecting particular cell in grid and change it, but it will not getting reflect in database Or else i am not sure about it after making changes in datasource try refreshing the grid but it will goes to it's initial form..